# JAX Apply function only on slice of array under jit

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I am using JAX, and I want to perform an operation like

```py
@jax.jit
def fun(x, index):
    x[:index] = other_fun(x[:index])
    return x
```

This cannot be performed under `jit`. Is there a way of doing this with `jax.ops` or `jax.lax`?
I thought of using `jax.ops.index_update(x, idx, y)` but I cannot find a way of computing `y` without incurring in the same problem again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423274/2937831) by @rvinas using `dynamic_slice` works well if your index is static, but you can also accomplish this with a dynamic index using `jnp.where`. For example:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def other_fun(x):
    return x + 1

@jax.jit
def fun(x, index):
  mask = jnp.arange(x.shape[0]) < index
  return jnp.where(mask, other_fun(x), x)

x = jnp.arange(5)
print(fun(x, 3))
# [1 2 3 3 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are two issues in your implementation. First, the slices are producing dynamically shaped arrays (not allowed in jitted code). Second, unlike numpy arrays, JAX arrays are immutable (i.e. the contents of the array cannot be changed).

You can overcome the two problems by combining `static_argnums` and [`jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice.html). Here is an example:

```
def other_fun(x):
    return x + 1

@jax.partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def fun(x, index):
    update = other_fun(x[:index])
    return jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice(x, update, (0,))

x = jnp.arange(5)
print(fun(x, 3))  # prints [1 2 3 3 4]
```

Essentially, the example above uses `static_argnums` to indicate that the function should be recompiled for different `index` values and `jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice` creates a copy of `x` with updated values at `:len(update)`.